# Excel Macro VBA Not Instr

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to modify code that I found. It is a VBA function that searches for all instances of a cell value, then returns a cell value from each instance into one cell.  I am attempting to only return values that have not already been found and therefore end up with a cell that does not contain duplicates.

Original Code:

```
Function Lookup_concat(Search_string As String, _
Search_in_col As Range, Return_val_col As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String
For i = 1 To Search_in_col.Count
If Search_in_col.Cells(i, 1) = Search_string Then
result = result & " " & Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value
End If
Next
Lookup_concat = Trim(result)
End Function
```

I have modified the code to this, I've indented the edit instead of keeping it on the same line to make it easier to read

```
Function Lookup_concat(Search_string As String, _
Search_in_col As Range, Return_val_col As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String
For i = 1 To Search_in_col.Count
If Search_in_col.Cells(i, 1) = Search_string 
      And Not (InStr(1, result, Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then
result = result & " " & Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value
End If
Next
Lookup_concat = Trim(result)
End Function
```

This version is the closest to the PHP `!strstr` function (that I do understand) and perhaps trying to apply PHP techniques to VBA is where I'm going wrong.  My thoughts are that the result string is actually filled AFTER my `Instr` command which is why it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to use two `If`s. You want to only add based on the string being in a range and also only if the string has not already been added.

Try this:

```
Function Lookup_concat(Search_string As String, _
Search_in_col As Range, Return_val_col As Range)
   Dim i As Long
   Dim result As String

   For i = 1 To Search_in_col.Count

      If (Instr(1, Search_in_col.Cells(i, 1), Search_string) > 0 )
          And ( InStr(1, result, Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 0 ) Then

         result = result & " " & Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value

      End If

   Next

   Lookup_concat = Trim(result)

End Function
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Sorry for the slow response, I haven't been at work since last week

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you are looking for ?

```
Function Lookup_concat(Search_string As String, Search_in_col As Range, Return_val_col As Range)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String
    For i = 1 To Search_in_col.Count
        If InStr(1, Search_in_col.Cells(i, 1).Value, Search_string, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            result = result & " " & Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next
    Lookup_concat = Trim(result)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're doing with `Search_in_col` and `Return_val_col` but you definitely need to use an `If Instr() > 0` test.

If this results > 1, then you probably don't need to do anything.  If this results 0, then you will need to do your concatenation. That's the part where I'm not sure why you're passing `search_in_col.cells(i,1).Value` as the search parameter, but then concatenating with `Return_val_col.Cells(i,1).Value`, so you're not actually concatenating the value you're using as the search parameter...

```
'if the cell's value exists in the search_string
If InStr(1, Search_in_col.Cells(i, 1).Value, search_string, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    'probably you want to do nothing here, since it's already existing
Else:
    'the cell's value does not exist in the search_string, so concatenate it
    result = result & " " & "whatever value you want to append to the result"
End If
```

Comment: Good explanation, thank you.  I have already accepted the previsou answer, but this is certainly very helpful